# Converting SpatialLite.Core.API.IGeometry to GeoAPI.Geometries.IGeometry

Tags: openstreetmap, convert, spatialite, .net

I have an in-house .NET library which processes geometry data in GeoAPI form (https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/GeoAPI). Within this library I have a method which I need to call which is expecting a GeoAPI.Geometries.IGeometry parameter.

I'm processing OSM PBF data using the PbfReader in SpatialLite.Osm (http://spatial.litesolutions.net/index.html). This gives me objects which implement SpatialLite.Core.API.IGeometry.

My question is how can acheive a conversion from SpatialLite.Core.API.IGeometry to GeoAPI.Geometries.IGeometry? I've made a few searches and found nothing to help me. I can go about creating a conversion procedure myself but it strikes me that there might be a better way.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Use a common geometry binary/wire format that both GeoAPI and SpatialLite.Core can understand, like WKB or WKT

Then have your GeoAPI geometry output to WKB/WKT and have your WKB/WKT reader class from SpatialLite.Core read from the WKB/WKT

Comment: WKB (or EWKB if the GeoAPI reader supports it) would be a better bet than WKT.

Answer (score 0):

Exporting to WKB and parsing that using NetTopologySuite's WKB Reader is one way to go, you could also use a converter like this:
https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/NetTopologySuite/tree/master/NetTopologySuite.Converter/NetTopologySuite.Converter.SpatialLite